# Devise Facebook The parameter app_id is required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

I did have this working, but when now trying to sign up, or log in via FB i get the dreaded `The parameter app_id is required` on the FB redirect.

**my gems:**

```
#User authentication
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

**devise.rb**

```
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'], scope: "email", info_fields: 'email, first_name, last_name'
```

**.env**

```
export FACEBOOK_APP_ID='******'
export FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET='*****'
```

Have just doubled checked the IDs are correct in my FB app, and they are. Also checked for outdated gems. I did need to update omniauth 1.7.1, but apart from  that, I can't see the issue!

Comment: Did you check what ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'] returns inside the code ? (with a debugger like byebug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked what return the environment variable, I think the problem is declaring environment variable, same as for me then I did declare the different way. On the `Gemfile` add the gem

```
gem 'figaro'
```

Then

```
bundle exec figaro install
```

Generated new file `# config/application.yml`

Then declare your environment variable and restart your server, for clearing then go to [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)

I think will help

Comment: I actually already have the figaro gem and have other variables stored in `config/application.yml`.  I've just added the two FB variables, but still can't get it to work.

Comment: @SimonCooper Have read carefully the devise omniauth doc https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: Actually just went through it again and have managed to redirect through to FB.  However I now have an issue with duplicate email, so I guess that's a different issue.